# Javascript - stub/substitute of object

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, web-worker, stub

In GWT framework there is a class JsoSplittable, which contains following code (`$wnd` is reference to global `window` object):

```
  return $wnd.JSON && $wnd.JSON.stringify && $wnd.JSON.stringify({
    b : function() {
    }
  }) == '{}';
```

I'm using this code in HTML5 web worker, which doesn't have access to `window` (therefore global `$wnd` can be redefined). How can I create in pure Javascript custom `$wnd` object which will satisfy condition in snippet above?

True can be hardcoded, I will force modern browser anyway.

PS: patch to GWT will be submitted, but I also need workaround for legacy environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your easiest bet

```
$wnd = {JSON: JSON};
```

If you don't have access to `JSON`, you could stub that out too

```
$wnd = {JSON: {stringify: function() { return '{}'; }}};
```

---

```
$wnd.JSON && $wnd.JSON.stringify && $wnd.JSON.stringify({b : function() {}}) == '{}';
// true
```